# Can a maxitrol function as a cut-off valve?

Tags: natural-gas

All the natural gas plumbing in my home was replaced a year ago.  I recently tried to find the gas cutoffs for my stove top and oven (separate appliances) but all I found was maxitrols.  Can maxitrols substitute for cutoff valves?  Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, that is a gas pressure REGULATOR not a shutoff valve.  There should be a shut off valve in the line somewhere, did you check near the meter?

[Maxitrol Regulator Diagram](https://www.maxitrol.com/rubber-seat-poppet-design/)

Comment: I presume there is a main cutoff near the meter.  I was looking for a cutoff for each appliance.  Is one cutoff for the whole house all that is required by most codes? (I am in New York State.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the practice or codes in NY, but it seems that a shutoff valve near an application, even if not required by code, is a good idea.  You might check the applicable codes for your locality and see what it says.